# Why isn't the CSS from my JsFiddle working the same way in my server?

Tags: css

I have the following JSFiddle, which positions an "X" to the left of a pop-out window: http://jsfiddle.net/XDaEk/601/

CSS:

```
.x {
    display: none;
   position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left:60px;
    transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
}

.x:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
.x:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 32px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}


.alert-div {
  display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    opacity:0.7;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="alert-div2"> <div class="x"></div>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis …</div>
```

If I copy this exact same CSS & HTML into my file on byethost.com, the "x" appears in the center of the screen. I surrounded the CSS with `<style type="text/css"> </style>` in the head. The HTML is in the body. I've tried copying this CSS & HTML into another JSFiddle and it works, so it seems to have something to do with Byethost.

There are no console errors related to this.

Here's the actual site. The button to show pop out is at the very bottom. It says "Post Message"  http://carouseltest.byethost8.com/aplayground.php    (Neither of the 2 errors on the console have to do with this code. They were there before I added this.)

Here's a photo of how it appears on Byethost: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAxXn.jpg

Comment: On your site press F12 and read the errors

Comment: @j08691 Neither of those errors are related to any of this; they were there before I put this on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `position: fixed` is being overridden (although it's difficult to be certain when it's not reproducible). Try updating to:

```
.x {
    display: none;

    /* add !important in case this is what's getting zapped and affecting layout */
    position: fixed !important;

    top: 25%;
    left:60px;
    transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
```